# What is a Jump list in Windows?

Tags: windows, jumplist

In Windows 8, when I right-click the taskbar and choose `Properties`, I see a new second tab called `Jump lists` instead of `Start Menu`:

[image: jump lists]

What are these lists and where can I access them?

Comment: Note that this applies equally well to Windows 7 (and is even reduced in Windows 8 as they aren't available on the start screen)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A jump list means those documents you have opened recently. When you right-click a pinned item in the taskbar, it will show up. That means when it is checked, Windows will remember which documents have been opened, so that they can be displayed.

Example of a jump list:

[image: Jump list]

Source: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/windows-8-jump-lists-comes-with-better-privacy-options/

Answer (score 3):

That is a Jump List. Accessed by right-clicking the application in the taskbar.

[image: Jump list]

Comment: Just align the arrow a bit more to the left and that would be perfect :)

Comment: @mwong Haha, there you go =D

Answer (score 1):

A jump list is the list of files, folders, or functions that you can access when you right click an app.

Answer (score 1):

Jump lists are the menus that appear when you right-click a taskbar button (they could also be shown in the Windows 7 start menu, but that's gone in Windows 8):

[image]

As you can see, they can contain various things, among them:

- Most **frequently** used items (e.g. in Windows Media Player)
- Most **recently** used items (pretty much the default when you don't do anything)
- Other categories that are application-defined, such as Chrome's *Recently closed*
- **Tasks** that are not document-centric but instead do something with an already-opened application. E.g. Chrome or IE allow you to open a new window or tab, Skype allows you to change the Online status, etc.